# Alternative method to detect small grains beside larger ones in HED algorithm

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

[image]

My main task in my project is to detect the properties of the polygons encountered in the images of soil particles ,I use HED algorithm to detect the borders of the grains in the image as it is very intelligent in detecting the borders efficiently and is not affected by the noise in the image ,and it is based on deep neural network in opencv library however I faced a problem in case of taking images of small grains beside large grains as shown in the following image as it detect perfectly the larger ones and neglect to great extent the small grains , I don't know how to fix this issue as it affects the results I get from the image analysis .
My main question if there a way to enhance the efficiency of the algorithm to detect both grains effectively. 
Find also attached the HED algorithm used .. I am using Canon 600D so I don't have doubt of the efficiency of the quality of images .

[image]

and the algorithm used HED

```
# USAGE
# python detect_edges_image.py --edge-detector hed_model --image images/guitar.jpg

# import the necessary packages
import argparse
import cv2
import os
import easygui

path = easygui.fileopenbox()
print(path)
hdir = os.path.dirname(path)
print(hdir)
hfilename = os.path.basename(path)
print(hfilename)
hname = os.path.splitext(hfilename)[0]
print(hname)
houtname = hname+"_out.jpg"
print(houtname)
hout = os.path.sep.join([hdir,houtname])
print(hout)

# # construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
# ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ap.add_argument("-d", "--edge-detector", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to OpenCV's deep learning edge detector")
# ap.add_argument("-i", "--image", type=str, required=True,
#   help="path to input image")
# args = vars(ap.parse_args())

class CropLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, params, blobs):
        # initialize our starting and ending (x, y)-coordinates of
        # the crop
        self.startX = 0
        self.startY = 0
        self.endX = 0
        self.endY = 0

    def getMemoryShapes(self, inputs):
        # the crop layer will receive two inputs -- we need to crop
        # the first input blob to match the shape of the second one,
        # keeping the batch size and number of channels
        (inputShape, targetShape) = (inputs[0], inputs[1])
        (batchSize, numChannels) = (inputShape[0], inputShape[1])
        (H, W) = (targetShape[2], targetShape[3])

        # compute the starting and ending crop coordinates
        self.startX = int((inputShape[3] - targetShape[3]) / 2)
        self.startY = int((inputShape[2] - targetShape[2]) / 2)
        self.endX = self.startX + W
        self.endY = self.startY + H

        # return the shape of the volume (we'll perform the actual
        # crop during the forward pass
        return [[batchSize, numChannels, H, W]]

    def forward(self, inputs):
        # use the derived (x, y)-coordinates to perform the crop
        return [inputs[0][:, :, self.startY:self.endY,
                self.startX:self.endX]]

# load our serialized edge detector from disk
print("[INFO] loading edge detector...")

fpath = os.path.abspath(__file__)
fdir =  os.path.dirname(fpath)
print(fdir)
protoPath = os.path.sep.join([fdir,"hed_model", "deploy.prototxt"])
print(protoPath)
modelPath =  os.path.sep.join([fdir,"hed_model","hed_pretrained_bsds.caffemodel"])
print(modelPath)

net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(protoPath, modelPath)

# register our new layer with the model
cv2.dnn_registerLayer("Crop", CropLayer)

# load the input image and grab its dimensions
image = cv2.imread('PATH')
# image = cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(image1,10,20)
(H, W) = image.shape[:2]
# print(image.shape[:2])
# image.shape[:2] =(H*3, W*3)ho
# image = cv2.resize(image,0.5)

# convert the image to grayscale, blur it, and perform Canny
# edge detection
print("[INFO] performing Canny edge detection...")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
# blurred = cv2.addWeighted(gray,1.5,blurred,-0.5,0)
canny = cv2.Canny(blurred,30, 150)


# construct a blob out of the input image for the Holistically-Nested
# Edge Detector

# cc = cv2.cvtColor(canny, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
# image = image+cc

# mean = (104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),

blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(image, scalefactor=1.0, size=(W, H),
                             # mean=(110,95,95),
                             mean=(104.00698793, 116.66876762, 122.67891434),
                            # mean=(104, 116, 122),
                            #  mean=(150, 120, 130),
                            #  mean=(145, 147, 180),
                             swapRB= False, crop=False)
print( blob)
cv2.waitKey(0)
# set the blob as the input to the network and perform a forward pass
# to compute the edges
print("[INFO] performing holistically-nested edge detection...")
net.setInput(blob)
hed = net.forward()
hed = cv2.resize(hed[0, 0], (W, H))
hed = (255 * hed).astype("uint8")

# show the output edge detection results for Canny and
# Holistically-Nested Edge Detection
cv2.imshow("Input", image)
cv2.imshow("Canny", canny)
cv2.imshow("HED", hed)
cv2.imwrite(hout, hed)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I found that the mean values are very effective in the algorithm in the function cv2.dnn.blobFromImage()

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using the HED algorithm, another approach is to use [connected component labeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling) already implemented as [`cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#ga107a78bf7cd25dec05fb4dfc5c9e765f). We can use this to separate objects and label cluster of pixels into individual segments.

---

Binary image

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian Blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
```

Connected component labeling to create false color image

[image]

```
# Perform connected component labeling
n_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity=4)

# Create false color image and color background black
colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(n_labels, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
colors[0] = [0, 0, 0]  # for cosmetic reason we want the background black
false_colors = colors[labels]
```

Now that we have segmented clusters of pixels, we can find the centroid of each labeled object. This information is already contained in the `centroid` variable returned from `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats`

[image]

```
# Obtain centroids
false_colors_centroid = false_colors.copy()
for centroid in centroids:
    cv2.drawMarker(false_colors_centroid, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])),
                   color=(255, 255, 255), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS)
```

There's a lot of centroids. We can filter using contour area to only keep the larger objects by using the information contained in `stats`.

[image]

```
# Only keep larger objects by filtering using area
MIN_AREA = 50
false_color_centroid_filter = false_colors.copy()
for i, centroid in enumerate(centroids[1:], start=1):
    area = stats[i, 4]
    if area > MIN_AREA:
        cv2.drawMarker(false_color_centroid_filter, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])),
                       color=(255, 255, 255), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS)
```

Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Load image, grayscale, Gaussian Blur, Otsu's threshold
image = cv2.imread('1.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (3,3), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# Perform connected component labeling
n_labels, labels, stats, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, connectivity=4)

# Create false color image and color background black
colors = np.random.randint(0, 255, size=(n_labels, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
colors[0] = [0, 0, 0]  # for cosmetic reason we want the background black
false_colors = colors[labels]

# Obtain centroids
false_colors_centroid = false_colors.copy()
for centroid in centroids:
    cv2.drawMarker(false_colors_centroid, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])),
                   color=(255, 255, 255), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS)

# Only keep larger objects by filtering using area
MIN_AREA = 50
false_color_centroid_filter = false_colors.copy()
for i, centroid in enumerate(centroids[1:], start=1):
    area = stats[i, 4]
    if area > MIN_AREA:
        cv2.drawMarker(false_color_centroid_filter, (int(centroid[0]), int(centroid[1])),
                       color=(255, 255, 255), markerType=cv2.MARKER_CROSS)

cv2.imshow('binary', thresh)
cv2.imshow('false_colors', false_colors)
cv2.imshow('false_colors_centroids', false_colors_centroid)
cv2.imshow('false_color_centroid_filter', false_color_centroid_filter)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: Thank you ,Very well . However ,I think that we have to apply a strong filter on the image so as to minimize noise in the binary image and which affect the final result of separation of grains .. furthermore ,I am afraid of getting more than one grain as one unit using this method as I use watershed segmentation after getting the edge detection image and gets good results

Comment: Yes there is a tradeoff, you could apply a larger blur to remove the smaller objects but you will also lose detail

Comment: I would like to get the count of objects based on size. How to do it ?